# ASP.NET MVC 3: How to get User's Role in a Controller Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, authorization, asp.net-4.0

I want to be able to

1. Get a list of roles of the current authenticated user.
2. Filter the data provided to that user based on their role.

I see ways to check if the user is in a particular role, but I don't care what role they participate.  The database will know what roles are allowed to see what data.  I need to submit a collection of these roles to the data service to filter the data based on those roles.

So first step is how do I get all roles associated with the current user in a controller method?

EDIT:

This seemed to work out nicely:

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)
```

Supporting answers still welcome.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Roles.GetRolesForUser(User.Identity.Name)
```

Comment: did you answer your own question?

Comment: Well, it was up there forever so I could have either deleted it, or answered it. :)

Comment: It's preferable for somebody to answer their own question to not having a clearly defined answer when somebody comes searching. Thank you for doing so.

Answer (score 13):

This can be done with a single statement:

```
User.IsInRole("admin");
```

Comment: While this does tell you if a user is in a specific role or not, it does not address the original question which asked how to get a list or array of all the user's roles.

Answer (score 10):

If anyone need this information, in case your user has many roles but you're looking for one, you could do this:(i thought id share)

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
   string[] roles = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
   foreach (string role in roles)
   {
       if (role.Contains("admin"))
       {
           <li>@Html.ActionLink("Administration", "Admin", "Movies")</li>
           break;
       }
   }
}
```